# Why does creating a map function whose parameter is of type `Nothing => U` appear to work?

Tags: scala, parameters

I'm writing Scala code that uses an API where calls to the API can either succeed, fail, or return an exception. I'm trying to make an `ApiCallResult` monad to represent this, and I'm trying to make use of the Nothing type so that the failure and exception cases can be treated as a subtype of any `ApiCallResult` type, similar to None or Nil. What I have so far appears to work, but my use of Nothing in the `map` and `flatMap` functions has me confused. Here's a simplified example of what I have with just the `map` implementation:

```
  sealed trait ApiCallResult[+T] {
    def map[U]( f: T => U ): ApiCallResult[U]
  }

  case class ResponseException(exception: APICallExceptionReturn) extends ApiCallResult[Nothing] {
    override def map[U]( f: Nothing => U ) = this
  }

  case object ResponseFailure extends ApiCallResult[Nothing] {
    override def map[U]( f: Nothing => U ) = ResponseFailure
  }

  case class ResponseSuccess[T](payload: T) extends ApiCallResult[T] {
    override def map[U]( f: T => U ) = ResponseSuccess( f(payload) )
  }

  val s: ApiCallResult[String] = ResponseSuccess("foo")
  s.map( _.size )  // evaluates to ResponseSuccess(3)

  val t: ApiCallResult[String] = ResponseFailure
  t.map( _.size )  // evaluates to ResponseFailure
```

So it appears to work the way I intended with `map` operating on successful results but passing failures and exceptions along unchanged. However using Nothing as the type of an input parameter makes no sense to me since there is no instance of the Nothing type. The `_.size` function in the example has type `String => Int`, how can that be safely passed to something that expects `Nothing => U`? What's really going on here?

I also notice that the Scala standard library avoids this issue when implementing None by letting it inherit the `map` function from Option. This only furthers my sense that I'm somehow doing something horribly wrong.

Comment: Do you really need to distinguish between failures and exceptions? If you re-cast a failure to `ApiFailure`, inheriting from `Throwable`, you can now restructure your ApiCallResult into `Try[+T]`. This allows failure and error propagation to proceed naturally, without re-implementation. When you need to distinguish failures from exceptions, you can pattern match on `ApiFailure`, etc.

Comment: @BobDalgleish I think that approach or variations thereof are definitely worth considering, but I'd still like to understand whether the use of Nothing here is really correct and why.

Comment: I expanded my comments in an answer below. I did some studying on how `Nothing` is used by both `Try` and `List`/`Nil`. Your approach leads you into troubles where you have to use `map` of `Nothing` to something. If you move the `map` for `ResponseFailure` up to the parent trait, you can implement `map` the same way that `List` does. On the other hand, you have to have a type parameter for `ResponseException` in the same way that `Try` implements `Failure`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things are aligning to make this happen, all having to do with covariance and contravariance in the face of a bottom type:

1. `Nothing` is the bottom type for all types, e.g. every type is its super.
2. The type signature of `Function1[-T, +R]`, meaning it accepts any type which is a super of `T` and returns any type for which `R` is a super.
3. The type `ApiCallResult[+R]` means any type `U` for which `R` is a super of `U` is valid.

So any type is a `super` of `Nothing` means both any argument type is valid and the fact that you return something typed around `Nothing` is a valid return type.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you don't need to distinguish failures and exceptions most of the time.

```
type ApiCallResult[+T] = Try[T]
case class ApiFailure() extends Throwable

val s: ApiCallResult[String] = Success("this is a string")

s.map(_.size)

val t: ApiCallResult[String] = Failure(new ApiFailure)
t.map(_.size)
```

To pick up the failure, use a `match` to select the result:

```
t match {
case Success(s) =>
case Failure(af: ApiFailure) =>
case Failure(x) =>
}
```